# Merge multiple arrays of objects based on property conditions

Tags: javascript

I have the following JSON:

```
"A series":[
   {
      "month":"2017 january",
      "value":77.2
   },
   {
      "month":"2017 february",
      "value":11.9
   },
   {
      ...
   }
],
"Main serie":[
   {
      "month":"2017 january",
      "value":3000050.0
   },
   {
      "month":"2017 february",
      "value":6520575.0
   },
   {
      ...
   }
],
"B series":[
   {
      "month":"2017 january",
      "value":55000.0
   },
   {
      ...
   }
]
```

I'd like to combine them into one array which looks something like this:

```
{
   "month":"2017 january",
   "Main serie":3000050.0,
   "A series":77.2,
   "B series":55000.0
},
{
   "month":"2017 february",
   "Main serie":6520575.0,
   "A series":11.9,
   "B series":75000.0
},
{
   "month":"2017 march",
   "Main serie":6955250.0,
   "A series":66.4,
   "B series":85000.0
},
{
   ...
},
```

The series can be 2, 3 or more, where the Main series is the principal and I receive it in position 2 or 3. And the year/month is the value that is repeated.

Comment: welcome! please take the time to attempt a solution for yourself and if you have specific problems, let us know. we aren't going to give you a solution without some effort.

Comment: Just to get you ahead, there is no fancy or robust solution for what you want. You probably will need a few loop structures in your code.

Comment: @PedroLima I think you could actually take care of it with a simple parse and reduce.

Comment: @DanielA.White Thank you. I got it. I am a beginner in this. I tried dozens of codes and the truth is that I didn't knew where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested `reduce` like this. Create an accumulator with unique `month` as key and keep updating it

```js
const input={"A series":[{"month":"2017 january","value":77.2},{"month":"2017 february","value":11.9},],"Main serie":[{"month":"2017 january","value":3000050},{"month":"2017 february","value":6520575},],"B series":[{"month":"2017 january","value":55000},{"month":"2017 february","value":3000050},]}

const merged = Object.entries(input).reduce((r, [k, v]) => {
      v.reduce((acc, { month, value }) =>{
          acc[month] = acc[month] || { month }
          acc[month][k] = value;
          return acc
        }, r)
        
        return r;
      }, {})
      
const output = Object.values(merged)
console.log(output)
```